# How to reference variable fields throughout a SELECT query?

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

Is there a way to refer to CASE WHEN statements in a query without writing the entire statement each time?  I'm writing in PL/SQL and have a few CASE WHEN statements I need to work with.

1. Some SELECT CASE WHEN statements and other calculated fields are dependent upon the CASE WHEN statements
2. I have CASE WHEN statements in my WHERE clause
3. I have CASE WHEN statements in my ORDER BY clause

I read [this explanation on aliases](http://joecelkothesqlapprentice.blogspot.ch/2006/06/reference-alias-field-name.html), which makes sense.  But is there a better way than copy/pasting lines on lines of code, confusing myself as I go?

```
SELECT
field1
,field2
,CASE WHEN a then b when c then d else more_stuff END AS total_days
,CASE WHEN a + 2 then b when c + 2 then d else even_more_stuff END AS total_ad_days

FROM
table1
JOIN table2

WHERE
CASE WHEN a + 2 then b when c + 2 then d else even_more_stuff END BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) and TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 7
```

This is what it looks like right now, but my CASE WHENs are long enough that it's cumbersome to have that much more code to look through and ensure accuracy of.

Comment: `TRUNC()` and PL/SQL imply you're using Oracle, not MySQL. Tagged accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an alias in the same query as it was defined. To solve that common issue, you can use a sub-query of a CTE. The later has my favor:

```
with V as (
    SELECT
      field1
      ,field2
      ,CASE WHEN a then b when c then d else more_stuff END AS total_days
      ,CASE WHEN a + 2 then b when c + 2 then d else even_more_stuff END AS total_ad_days

    FROM
    table1
    JOIN table2
    ON ...
)

SELECT * FROM V 
WHERE total_ad_days BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) and TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 7
```